# How can I make a favorite icon with white border and background color?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve the icon you can see in the image, it is a favorite icon with white border and some background color, just to be clear, not the functionality because I think I can handle this just changing the background color with some boolean variable. I have tried stack, and Icon.favorite_border, and Icon.favorite, but I had no success.

I appreciate your help.

[Icon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UELEO.png)

Comment: Image editing software. Then export it in different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately I have the svg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could give you an idea on implementing using `Stack`

1. With same icon (by adjusting height)

```
    Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 50.0,
              child: Center(
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Icon(Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.white, size: 50.0),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red, size: 40.0))
                ]
            ),
        ),
     ),
```

[image]

2. With complementary icon set, no size adjustment.

```
   SizedBox(
    height: 50.0,
    width: 50.0,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red), 
        Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white)
         ],
     ),
  ),
```

[image]

Hope this suits your case!

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because this was what I was trying, however I ended following the advice of the comment above.

Comment: Yeah, Sometimes it is better to go with images. Happy Coding!